# size of database after restored from sql dump

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have 5 gb PostgreSQL dump file. I will restore it by `psql` command but I have no space on my computer (about 1 gb). I want to know, will the database take over than or equal to 5 gb?

Comment: Why would you think it would take less space after it is restored? If you do think it would take less space why not try it and see what happens? Worst case scenario the restore fails.

Comment: because i dont know. @igor

Comment: hey, i wonder if will it take equal or more space than 5 gb. please help @Igor

Comment: hey, i wonder if will it take equal or more space than 5 gb. please help @dfundako

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SQL dump is typically a lot smaller than the restored database, because it only contains the *definition* of indexes, not the actual index data. So you should expect the database to need at least 5GB after being restored. If it contains a lot of indexes it might be substantially be bigger.

The only situation where a SQL dump *might* be bigger than the restored size is, if the dump contains a lot of text data that is longer than approximately 2KB. Any text value exceeding that size will automatically be compressed. But still it's very unlikely that the restored size will be 5 times smaller than the dump.

Comment: thank you so much. that was the answer i was looking for. i restored db from dump but i tried to queryed for an id. after a few mins, db were in recover mode. is it impossible to query a large sql file with 4gb ram computer? is there any way to query faster?